# How close app when onBackPress in HomeFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onbackpressed

I want to close app from HomeFragment, But the app goes to the splash page.

I have the navigation drawer, i want when backPress in any fragment move to homeFragment and when backPress in HomeFragment show the toast message to click back again to exit the app

How to make the homeFragment close app

The HomeFragment Java code:

```
import.....

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed {
    View view;
    private long backPressedTime;
    private Toast backToast;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);  ....    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            backToast.cancel();
            getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
            getActivity().finish();
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            backToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.press_agin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            backToast.show();
        }
        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call finish() after you start home activity from splash.

Comment: @KishanSolanki I have the navigation drawer, i want when backPress in any fragment move to homeFragment and when backPress in HomeFragment show the toast message to click back again to exit the app

Answer (score 1):

Hey Aws Hakam you should call finishAffinity() instead of finish() to finish all the activities below your current activity in the stack but remember it will only finish activities which are of same task and have same affinity . For detail go to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAffinity())

```
activity.finishAffinity();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your SplashActivity was not finished when you started the HomeActivity. It only went to the background. In your SplashActivity, call `finish()` after starting your HomeActivity

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because your splash activity it not finished yet add this  line when starting activity from splash screen:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: I have the navigation drawer, i want when backPress in any fragment move to homeFragment and when backPress in HomeFragment show the toast message to click back again to exit the app

Comment: @awshakam98 Did you win?  , I want to achieve same thing ,  if you manage to win help me ,would appreciate it